# Creating my own ViewModelStore to control ViewModel lifecycle

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

It is stated in google example that to communicate from fragment to fragment, you could use the `ViewModel` scoped to the `Activity`. The problem with this approach is that, then the `ViewModel` will last until the `Activity` is destroyed.

In a Single `Activity` Application, this means that the activity will be littered with `ViewModel`s which might not be needed anymore. You will also have problem with states if these `ViewModel`s won't be cleared properly.

So I look around at how to alter the lifecycle of the `ViewModel` so that I doesn't have to be tied to the `Activity` lifecycle but be longer than the lifecycle of a `Fragment`. This will then be very useful for Multi-step / Transactional flow of screens where the requirements are filled-up during the screen flow process.

So basically, I would want a ViewModel to be scoped less than the activity but longer than a fragment.

To accomplish this, I created my own `ViewModelStore` and persist it across configuration the same way `FragmentActivity` persist its own `ViewModelStore`. Then when initializing the view model I will use,

`ViewModelProvider(myCustomViewModelStore, myFactory).get(SomeViewModelClass::class.java)`

Since the `ViewModel` is not scoped to my custom `ViewModelStore`, I could easily call `viewModelStore.clear()` to control the lifecycle of the `ViewModel`.

I was wondering whether this is a good idea and whether someone out there is using the same idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [Navigation Component 2.1.0-aplha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha02), `ViewModel`s can now be scoped to transaction flows through the `Navigation Component` navigation graph.